# Azure ScaleSet: Is possible to have an Internal load balancer and a public IP assigned to a scale set

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I need applications to communicate using internal loadbalanced IP, but at the same time need to RDP to the boxes using public IP.

Is such a thing possible? Or any alternative options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is such a thing possible?

No, Azure does not support assigning a Public IP address to internal LB.

> Or any alternative options?

As a workaround, we can create a VM in the same Vnet, work as a **jump box**.

If you want to RDP them directly, we can configure **HAproxy** on this VM, make this VM work as an internet Load Balancer.

Comment: thanks for the help could please elaborate or provide me a link on the HAproxy option?

Comment: @kumar We can refer to this [link](https://www.upcloud.com/support/haproxy-load-balancer-centos/) to deploy Haproxy, we can add vmss instances private IP addresses to `haproxy.cfg`.

Comment: @kumar please let me know if you need more help, Also, if it helps, please don't forget to accept it as an answer so that other community members will be benefited:)